Finding an apartment or house in Armenia
In USA, there's Zillow, RedFin, etc.
In Spain, fotocasa, idealista, etc.
What is the Armenian equivalent?
Prefer sites in English, Spanish, or Italian.
Can do Dutch, Portuguese, French but those are quite difficult for me.
I can't do Armenian yet.
Tried a web search but three USA-only sites cheated the SEO to the top of the list, and literally all the rest were for short-term/holiday rentals.

Local sites are probably best searched in local language. You can try Google Translate or something similar.

Do you have a friend/contact in Armenia who could help you search? Is the rental for holiday or longer-term?

I'd think Google Translate  wouldn't handle that sort of site very well.  But I can't try it if I don't know the URI of such a site.
